# Cannot play local video on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin

I want to play a local video inside my Xamarin.Android app but when I set the uri the Visual Studio output tells me that the app can't read the video.

My video is located in the "files" folder of my app:

- com.myapp.myap

  - cache/
  - files/

    - videos_files/

      - video.mp4

Here's my code:

```
var videoview = this.FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView);
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://com.myapp.com/files/videos_files/video.mp4");

videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
```

Comment: What is  the Build Action on your video file?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `android.resource://blahblahblah` format is only used when your files are included in your `Resources` folder with Build Action `AndroidResource`.

If you want this, then you can move your video file into `YourApp/Resources/Raw`.
Then set up your path:

```
string videoPath = $"android.resource://com.myapp.com/{Resource.Raw.video}";
videoView.SetVideoPath(videoPath);
```